# What does `const` behind a function header mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, constants

There is a `class A` and it has the following `operator()` implementation:

```
void A::operator()(...parameters...) const 
{
    // operator body
}
```

What does this `const` mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Methods in C++ can be marked as `const` like in the above example to indicate that the function does not modify the instance. To enforce this, the `this` pointer is of type `const A* const` within the method.

Normally, the `this` pointer within a method is `A* const` to indicate that we cannot change what `this` points to. That is, so that we cannot do `this = new A()`.

But when the type is `const A* const` we also cannot change any of the properties.

Comment: The reason that you can't change `this` is because it is not an _lvalue_ expression, not because it has a `const` qualified type which it doesn't. In fact you cannot have _rvalues_ of `const` qualified non-class types.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Where did you find that information? The sources I've consulted explain that the pointer is of type `const A* const`: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr035.htm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytk2ae82.aspx

Comment: In the standard, section about `this` in chapter 9 and section about value categories in chapter 3.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Well that's certainly the most definitive source. Thanks for correcting the info I provided. For others interested, see http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/CS/C++draft/ISO-CPP-body.pdf page 155. Thanks Charles!

Comment: However, just to confuse the issue, const member functions can modify members explicitly marked as `mutable`.

Answer (score 2):

That the method uses `this` as a `const A*` and then can only call other `const` methods.

See [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10) entry of the CPP FAQ.

Comment: Small nitpick - the type actually becomes `const A* const`

Comment: @Cam: no, the type is simply `const A*`. `this` is an _rvalue_ which is why you can't assign to it or take its address, not because it's `const`.

Answer (score 1):

As already amply described, it means that the method will not modify the observable state of the object.  But also, and very importantly, it means the method can be called on a const object, pointer, or reference - a non-const method cannot.  ie:

```
class A
{
public:
    void Method1() const
    {
    }

    void Method2()
    {
    }
};

int main( int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/ )
{

    const A a;
    a.Method1(); //ok.
    a.Method2(); //compiler error!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please do not assume that it won't modify the object, only the visible state remains unchanged.

Comment: Also already amply stated.  : )  So far I'm the only person to point out that only const methods can be called on a const object.  Where's my upvotes!?!?

Comment: actually, you have an upvote from me, but also a downvote, because const methods may change the object. But they shall not change the externally visible state.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear that I was summarising the answers above, before adding the important bit.  I've now polished it.  Still, now I must find the downvoter and stalk them across the internet forever!  Where am I gonna find the time for that!?

Comment: You want to use '@' next time, so I will be notified ;) My (virtual) downvote vanishes, summing to +1. Btw, you've not received any real downvote.

Answer (score 0):

const keyword specifies that the function is a "read-only" function that does not modify the object for which it is called.

Answer (score 0):

It means that calling the operator will not change state of the object.

Comment: Not necessarily, thanks to `const_cast` and `mutable`.

Comment: @dan04: Ok, so it means "will not change state of the object... unless someone cheats!" :P

Comment: @dan04: mutating a const value via `const_cast` yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: @piokuc: Maybe refine this to "observable state".

Comment: Sure, yes, in general it does not have to be true, but I just wanted to give an answer which would be more useful for a novice C++ programmer than 'it means that type of this will be const A* const in the function'.

Comment: @phresnel What's the difference between state and observable state?

Comment: @piokuc: Example: You have a quadtree class. Under the hood, the quadtree is build up lazily, i.e. on demand; this lazyness is hidden from users of the class. Now, a query-method on that quadtree should be `const`, because querying a quadtree is expected to not change the quadtree. How do you implement const-correctness and lazyness without breaking C++' rules? Use `mutable`. Now you have a quadtree that for the user looks const, but you know that under the hood, there's still a lot of change.

Comment: @phresnel Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the idea of 'observable state' even though I knew about mutable keyword. I have some doubts about const-correctness achieved this way - is it worth the trouble if you know the compiler cannot check it? I mean, if you "cheat" with const_cast the compiler is aware of it, which in theory can help it in taking some optimization decisions, whereas I don't think it is possible to prove that modification to mutable members does not change the observable state, is it?... Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A `const` member function promises to not change the observable state of the object.

Under the hood, it might still change state, e.g. of `mutable` members. However, `mutable` members should never be visible from anywhere outside the class' interface, i.e. you should never attempt to lie to client code, because client code may validly expect that `const` functions don't tweak the object's outer hull. Think of `mutable` as an optimization tool (e.g. for caching and memoization).

---

Example for mutability:

You have a quadtree class. Under the hood, the quadtree is build up lazily, i.e. on demand; this lazyness is hidden from users of the class. Now, a query-method on that quadtree should be `const`, because querying a quadtree is expected to not change the quadtree. How do you implement const-correctness and lazyness without breaking C++' rules? Use `mutable`. Now you have a quadtree that for the user looks const, but you know that under the hood, there's still a lot of change:

```
class Quadtree {
public:
    Quadtree (int depth);
    Foo query (Bar which) const;

private:
    mutable Node node_;
};
```